Value not getting reset during reset of form
In this code
May be I am resetting this form all the values ​​are getting reset but the value of swt_culture_type is not getting reset.
const { data: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["headerDataDetailsKey", props?.culture_test_header_id, props?.test_component_id],
    queryFn: async () => {
        return await GetCultureTestHeadersDetailsEP(props?.culture_test_header_id, props?.test_component_id, true, 5, 1);
    },
});

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (GetCultureTestHeadersDetails?.data?.culture_type) {
        reset({
            txt_code: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.culture_code,
            atc_test_component: {
                test_component_id: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.test_component_id,
                test_component_code: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.test_component_print_name,
                test_component_print_name: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.test_component_print_name,
                item_id: 0,
            },
            swt_is_colony_count: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.is_colony_count,
            txt_colony_count_label: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.colony_count_label,
            txt_colony_count_default_value: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.colony_count_default_value,
            swt_is_gram_strain: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.is_gram_strain,
            txt_gram_strain_label: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.gram_strain_label,
            ddl_gram_stain_default_value: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.gram_strain_default_value,
            swt_is_organism: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.is_organism_isolated,
            txt_organism_isolated_label: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.organism_isolated_label,
            ddl_organism_default_value: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.organism_isolated_default_value,
            swt_is_solid_media: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.is_solid_media,
            ddl_solid_media_default_value: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.solid_media_default_value,
            txt_solid_media_label: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.solid_media_label,
            swt_is_liquid_media: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.is_liquid_media,
            ddl_liquid_media_default_value: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.liquid_media_default_value,
            txt_liquid_media_label: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.liquid_media_label,
            swt_is_report_type: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.is_report_type,
            report_type_default_value: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.report_type_default_value,
            txt_report_type_label: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.report_type_label,
            txt_special_instructions: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.special_instruction,
            txt_description: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.description,
            ddl_max_count: Number(GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.max_result_count),
            swt_culture_type: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails?.data?.culture_type,
            swt_status: GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.status,
        });

        setValue("swt_culture_type", GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.culture_type);

        console.log("swt_culture_type:", GetCultureTestHeadersDetails.data.culture_type);
    }
}, [GetCultureTestHeadersDetails, GetCultureTestHeadersDetails?.data]);

I set value directly but still always shows true

All the values are getting reset, but the value of swt_culture_type is not. This is because you're logging the value within the same block where it's being set, causing the logged value to appear unchanged. Try logging the value outside of the same useEffect to see the updated value.
By separating the logging into a different useEffect, you can ensure that the log statement captures the updated state after it has been reset.
